# Logical AND OR and increment precedence

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-or

I want to ask a question about the code below.

```
int a=1, b=3, c=1;

if((a||c--)&&(c&&b--)) printf("%d",b);
printf("%d %d %d",a,b,c);
```

Why does the code prints "21 2 1" rather than "1 2 0" ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which part puzzles you, the additional digit at the start or the the 0? Please explain the reasoning behind the result you expect.

Comment: Or is evaluated using shirt circuit

Comment: @MrTux maybe trousers circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `||` and `&&` force left-to-right evaluation - the LHS is evaluated first *and all side effects applied*, then based on the result the RHS is evaluated.

Both operators short-circuit:

- for `a || b`, if `a` is non-zero, then the result of the expression is `1` regardless of the value of `b`, so `b` is not evaluated;
- for `a && b`, if `a` is zero, then the result of the expression is `0` regardless of the value of `b`, so `b` is not evaluated.

`&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so `a || b && c` is parsed as `a || (b && c)`.

Putting all that together, `(a||c--)&&(c&&b--)` is evaluated as follows:

1. `a || c--` is evaluated as follows:

   1. `a` is evaluated - its result is `1`, so

      `c--` is *not* evaluated; because of this `c`'s value is not changed, and

      the result of the expression is `1`

   `c && b--` is evaluated as follows:

   1. `c` is evaluated - its result is `1`, so

      `b--` is evaluated - its result is `3`; as a *side effect* `b` is decremented, and

      the result of the expression is `1`

   both `a || c--` and `c && b--` evaluate to `1`

The values of `a` and `c` are unchanged (`1` and `1`, respectively), while `b` has been decremented and its value is now `2`.

Answer (score 3):

Since the or is evaluated to true immediately in (a||c--), the c-- is never evaluated. The compiler does this. If a statement is true right off the bat, it won't bother evaluating the rest. So, c is never decremented as the right side of the or is never evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

You can imagine this if statement

```
if((a||c--)&&(c&&b--)) printf("%d",b);
```

the following way

```
if ( a )
{
    if ( c )
    {
        if ( b-- )
        {
            printf("%d",b);
        }
    }
}
else if ( c-- )
{
    if ( c )
    {
        if ( b-- )
        {
            printf("%d",b);
        }
    }
}
```

So if the expression in the first if statement

```
if ( a )
```

evaluates to the logical true then this if statement

```
else if ( c-- )
```

never gets the control.

From the C Standard (6.5.14 Logical OR operator)

> 4 Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees
> left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is
> a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
> operands. **If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second
> operand is not evaluated**.